# Change of table column name not reflected in Azure Data Factory after schema imports, saving, publishing

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory, copy-data

Have an azure data factory with a copy data step which reads data from a view (on a staging table) and pushes it into a database table.  In database changed column name from QuanityReqUoM to QuantityReqUoM in destination table.  In the Azure Data Factory I then re-imported the schema for the table destination dataset and reimported the mapping schemas in the Copy Data Activity in the pipeline.  Saved everything and then published, but when I trigger the pipeline I get:

> ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A
> database operation failed. Please search error to get more
> details.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Invalid
> column name 'QuanityRequiredUoM'. Invalid column name
> 'QuanityRequiredUoM'.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data
> Provider,SqlErrorNumber=207,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=207,State=1,Message=Invalid
> column name
> 'QuanityRequiredUoM'.,},{Class=16,Number=207,State=1,Message=Invalid
> column name 'QuanityRequiredUoM'.,},],'

Tried re-importing the schemas, both at the Destination dataset level and Pipeline Copy Data mapping level, re-saving and re-publishing with no effect.

Comment: Does the pipeline work in debug mode?

Comment: @Chris Albert, try deleting the pipeline, datasets and create it fresh. ADF has one bug like this where it goes into a cached state..Wondering why MS hasn't fixed it still.

Comment: Tried renaming original pipeline and recreating under same name, did not work.  Did not try deleting old pipeline or creating under new name as did not have time.  Took so long to get back to this as had other projects on plate.

Answer (score 1):

Select a dataset and there is a definition in JSON format, like:

```json
"schema": [
           {
               "name": "OrderId",
               "type": "integer",
               "precision": 0,
               "scale": 0
           },
           {
               "name": "Company",
               "type": "text",
               "precision": 0,
               "scale": 0
           },
```

Just add or modify the definition manually and press “OK”, and then go to the Copy Data or DataFlow activity and refresh/reset. It will bring the changes you made it to the JSON definition.

Comment: Vidya and Jeremy, thank you very much for taking the time to help me out on this.  Unfortunately, it did not work.  The JSON for the Dataset was correct, but the pipeline's was not.  I updated the pipeline's JSON so the target column was QuantityReqUoM as needed, but even after saving, publishing, and clearing the browse's cache, I was still getting the 'Invalid column name 'QuanityRequiredUoM'' error.  When looking at the pipeline's JSON, it now shows correct even after refreshing the page.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As suspected, an Id10t (me) error, issue was a trigger on the table referring to the column in question, once that was updated as well everything worked.  Either SQL Server did not pass the error source to Azure or the Azure did not display it.